# How is countably infinite addition defined

Tags: arithmetic, definition, arithmetic-functions

In the axiom of additivity of probability theory, the concept of a countably infinite sum, i. e. the sum of countably infinitely many real numbers, is used. Could someone please tell me how that kind of addition is defined?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics) (convergent ones, in particular). For probability measures all terms are positive which makes it easier.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite sum is defined as$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n $$  Where $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k$$

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

It is the sum of a convergent series, i.e., the limit of the increasing sequence formed by the sums of the first $n$ terms as $n$ tends towards infinity (or $+\infty$ itself if no finite limit exists).

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

In probability all the addends are positive so the partial sums are monotonically increasing.  The sum is bounded above by $1$, so the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) applies and the sum converges.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was going to say that probability theory's axioms therefore imply that every infinite series of disjoint sets in the sample space converges, so that confirms it.